# How to find out how long an array has to be when being initialized?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, byte-shifting

Imagine i have an byte-array ids.

Later i want to store data in it this way:

```
ids[cz << 24 | cx << 16 | y << 8 | z << 4 | x]
```

cz, cx, y, y, z, x are int values in this case.

So how long does the array need to be when i create it?
I thought i would have to initialize the array this way:

```
byte[] ids = new byte[maxCz * maxCx * maxY * maxZ * maxX];
```

But it always gives me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Not knowing what `maxCz`, `maxCx`, `maxZ`, or `maxX` are, hard to help you here.

Comment: they represent the max values for cz, cx, x, y, z. for example: int cx = 7, int cz = 7, x = 16, y = 256, z = 16.

Comment: Which would be?

Comment: Array size must accommodate max potential index value, so simple version is `ids[(maxCz + 1) << 24]`. Complex version is `ids[(maxCz << 24 | maxCx << 16 | maxY << 8 | maxZ << 4 | maxX) + 1]`. In both cases, I assume the max values are inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest component in the OR-ed expression is `cz << 24`. Assuming that `maxCz` is 2<sup>k</sup>-1, and that the remaining `max` values are selected in a way for the bits of different components to not overlap, you need to allocate

```
byte[] ids = new byte[(maxCz+1) << 24];
```

When `maxCz` is 7, this is a 128 MB allocation, so the array is going to be very large.